# #include don't really include the code in C++

Tags: c++, include

I have a class defined as follow:

**Mirf.h**

```
class Mirf{
public:
    void init(void);
};
```

**Mirf.cpp**

```
#include <Mirf.h>

Mirf mirf = Mirf();

Mirf::init(){
    [Some Code Here]
}
```

The class Wireless uses the Mirf instance:

**Wireless.h**

```
#include <Mirf.h>

class Wireless {
public:
    void init(void);
};
```

**Wireless.cpp**

```
#include <Wireless.h>
#include <Mirf.h>

Wireless::init(){
    mirf.init();
}
```

My main method:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <Wireless.h>
#include <Mirf.h>

Wireless wireless = Wireless();

int main(){
    wireless.init();
}
```

The code compiles normally but the `[Some Code Here]` in Mirf.cpp doesn't called:

What's is wrong in my code?

Comment: Maybe you need to flush your print buffer?

Comment: To add to Jim's comment, try putting `\n` at the end of the `printf` string

Comment: Since `Mirf` is a `Mirf24L`, it makes sense that `Mirf.init();` wouldn't invoke `Nrf24l::init()`. Should you be looking for `Mirf24L::init()` instead?

Comment: @Rob There is a couple of `extern` in my code, I'll edit my post. @Shahbaz and @Jim the printf is an example. Actually, I'll send that string to serial port. Something like `Serial.println("test");`

Comment: Please don't post code that is sort-of-like the code that is broken. Please create a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the error and then copy-paste (don't retype!) your program into a question. http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob, I'm so sorry. I'll modify my post.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but you still are posting code that doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please post an **actual** complete minimal program that demonstrates the error you have. The code you posted doesn't compile -- it defines `class Mirf` multiple times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5604/discussion-between-ricardogobbo-and-rob)

Answer (score 5):

Just because code is `#include`d doesn't mean that it will be called.  Only the `main` function is called automatically, any other functions need to be referenced inside expressions or they won't run.

Comment: That is only partly true. If there a static instance of some type `X`, then `X::X()` (or the specified constructor in general) will be called before `main`. Maybe that's the case, maybe not, but from the given code, that's guesswork.

Comment: @bitmask: I think you meant a namespace or class static member -- static locals aren't evaluated until the first time the function runs.  But I'm including initializers under the umbrella of "expressions".

Comment: I see. Well, you have to admit, that that's a stretch :)